# redirecting "tail --follow=name | grep" to a file

Tags: linux, redirect, grep

Here is my scenario:

I have a log file that is being wrote too by an application. The log file is named "alarms.log". I want to tail the file for a certain string and redirect that to a file called alarms.log.test. So i am using the below command.

```
tail --follow=name alarms.log | grep CEC >> alarms.log.test
```

Then i tail the file it is being redirected to by using this command:

```
tail --follow=name alarms.log.test
```

My problem is this: The file alarms.log.test is not getting anything in the file. I know for a fact that it should be. Because the string is being found. I believe the problem is that the redirect waits for a certain amount of data is read and then flushes to the redirect file, is that the case?

I need it to immediately flush to the file every time something is found. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use the `tee` command for this?

`The tee command is used to store and view (both at the same time) the output of any other command.`

Maybe something like the example linked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/59497/writing-tail-f-output-to-another-file/59518#59518)

`tail -f alarms.log | egrep --line-buffered 'name' | tee alarms.log.test`

Also see: http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/

Comment: so my new command would need to look like this: tail --follow=name alarms.log | grep CEC | tee -a alarms.log.test  ? If that is the case, it is still not writing it to the file. And i am not seeing anything output to the terminal.

Comment: Please see the edit and the SuperUser link. Buffering is the problem. Using the --line-buffered switch with egrep works.

Comment: @Prolink - you're buffering, that's why nothing is being written. ewwhite's answer had an option for grep to reduce the effects of buffering, you didn't use it and that's why it's still not working. Run his command *as he gave it to you* and try that.

Comment: Ha! I wrote mine after the edit, I didn't see the original answer.

Comment: @mfinni: I forgive you. <3